# Is there a way around SQL Servers deferred name resolution?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I just deployed a new stored proc to our test environment only to have it fail upon execution due to the fact the test system didn't contain a table that the stored proc relied upon. I believe this is due to [deferred name resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

The thing is, I feel that at times in the past, I have attempted to create stored procs that failed due to missing dependencies. I could be wrong though.

Anyway, is it possible to somehow enforce name resolution during creation of a stored proc? If so, is there any way to get this working with sqlcmd as well as SSMS?

This way we could find out about missing dependencies upon the rollout of scripts rather upon their first execution.

On a side note, I was interested to read about this apparent [deviation from the MSDN doco](http://techblog.julianhidalgo.com/2009/05/29/dont-trust-sql-server-2005-deferred-name-resolution/) regarding how deferred resolution works.

Edit: We have a mix of 2005/2008 (out of my control), so I'd need a 2005 solution to work on both instances.

Comment: You can vote on a [Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=127152) for it, but there doesn't seem to have been a lot of action on it (other than upvotes), and no listed workarounds.

Comment: Please state version of SQL Server

Comment: In your final para, I'm not sure that people are reading and understanding the whole MSDN document. It doesn't say it will error before it starts, it says "If the objects referenced by the stored procedure are missing when the stored procedure is executed, the stored procedure **stops executing when it gets to the statement that references the missing object.**" (My emphasis)

Comment: @Martin. I've edited the post to reflect the version used (2005).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the link and the clarification on the MSDN doco.

Answer (score 4):

You could investigate `WITH SCHEMABINDING` though that may not work for you for the reasons indicated in the comments to the connect item linked to by Damien.

If on SQL Server 2008 you could also look at `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

```
CREATE PROC bar
AS
SELECT * 
FROM DoesNotExist 
JOIN AlsoDoesNotExist ON 1=1

GO

CREATE TABLE DoesNotExist
(
X INT
)
GO

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,
       referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_id IS NULL
```

Returns

```
referencing_entity_name        referenced_entity_name
------------------------------ ------------------------------
bar                            AlsoDoesNotExist
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'll check them out tomorrow.

Comment: I was just doing some research on using WITH SCHEMABINDING for procedures. From what I've read, I am led to believe that SCHEMABINDING isn't currently available for stored procs. The comments in the link posted by Damien seem to indicate that if, in some future release, SCHEMABINDING was provided as an option for stored procs, then it could be undesireable. Would you suggest that procedured dependency checking just isn't really possible with 2005 other than at execution time?

Comment: Further to my comment above, it seems that the MSDN doco for sp_refreshsqlmodule - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754(v=SQL.90).aspx refers to "...nonschema-bound stored procedure..", so maybe my assumption regarding SCHEMABINDING for stored procs is incorrect. If so, do you have an idea on the syntax required? I tried; CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TGA_SB1]
 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM nothinghere
END
GO


but it didn't work.